# Reset State On Redirect Change

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, initialization, state

In my app.js component, I use a function to set the state of current when a click occurs in the saved component. However, I need to reset this state when the route changes and someone is no longer on the saved page.

I was thinking along the lines of resetting the state current whenever there's a route change from the saved component using history. But I'm not sure if that make sense or is doable

Here are parts of app.js

```
  state = {
    current: {},
  }

  handleDetailsClick = (word) => {
    console.log(`Fetching details for ${word.word}`);
    this.setState({ current: word });
  }


setRedirect = redirect =>{
    this.setState({redirect})
  }


render() {
    return (
      <>
        { this.state.modal === 'offline' ? <Offline closeModal={() => this.setModal(false)} /> : ''}

        <Route 
          render={ routeProps => <Redirector redirect={this.state.redirect} setRedirect={this.setRedirect} {...routeProps} />}
        />
        <header>
          <nav className="navbar">
            <Link  className="navbar-text" to='/'>The Lexicon</Link>
            <Link  className="navbar-text" to='/savedwords'>Saved</Link>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
        <Route
            render = { routeProps =>
              !routeProps.location.state?.alert ? '' :
              <div className="alert alert-primary position-relative float-right m-3">
                { routeProps.location.state.alert }
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/savedwords" render={routeProps =>
              <Saved 
                faves={this.state.faves}
                word={this.state.word} 
                current={this.state.current}
                handleSave={this.handleSave} 
                handleDetailsClick={this.handleDetailsClick}
                {...routeProps} />}
            />
            <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
            <Route path="/500" component={InternalServerError} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my react router

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Redirector extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // console.log('Redirector::componentDidUpdate');
    const {redirect, location, history, setRedirect} = this.props;
    const {path} = redirect;

    if (!path) return;

    if (path !== location.pathname) {
      // console.log('Redirector::performing redirect to', path);
      history.push({
        pathname: path,
      
      })
    }
    else {
      // console.log('Redirector:: clearing redirect');
      setRedirect({});
      setTimeout( () => history.replace({state: {}}), 4000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <></>;
  }
}

export default Redirector;

  // state: {alert},
  // const {path, alert} = redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change `<Link>` to just `<a>`

`<Link>` will keep the state, but `<a>` will request from scratch